# Flink on YARN : Amazon S3 wrongly used instead of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, flink-cep

I followed [Flink on YARN's setup documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/setup/yarn_setup.html). But when I run with `./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 2 -jm 1024 -tm 2048`, while being authenticated to Kerberos, I get the following error :

```
2016-06-16 17:46:47,760 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-06-16 17:46:48,518 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl     - Timeline service address: https://**host**:8190/ws/v1/timeline/
2016-06-16 17:46:48,814 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         - Using values:
2016-06-16 17:46:48,815 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -   TaskManager count = 2
2016-06-16 17:46:48,815 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -   JobManager memory = 1024
2016-06-16 17:46:48,815 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         -   TaskManager memory = 2048
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2623)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClientBase.deployInternal(FlinkYarnClientBase.java:531)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClientBase$1.run(FlinkYarnClientBase.java:342)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClientBase$1.run(FlinkYarnClientBase.java:339)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClientBase.deploy(FlinkYarnClientBase.java:339)
    at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli.run(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkYarnSessionCli.main(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:362)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2842)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 23 more
```

I set the following properties in my ***./flink-1.0.3/conf/flink-conf.yaml***

```
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /etc/hadoop/conf/
fs.hdfs.hdfssite: /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

**How can I use HDFS instead of Amazon's S3?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to set the env var HADOOP_CLASSPATH as suggested in a deleted answer.

@rmetzger: `fs.defaultFS` is set.

The resulting command :

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=... ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 2 -jm 1024 -tm 2048
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that Flink is not picking up your configuration file.

Can you remove the line starting with `fs.hdfs.hdfssite` from the configuration. Its not needed if `fs.hdfs.hadoopconf` is set.

Also, can you check if the setting for `fs.defaultFs` in `core-site.xml` is set to something starting with `hdfs://` ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip (hdfssite not usefull). fs.defaultFs is set to hdfs://***